# Given node for Storefront.Product with string id, how to get productId for Admin API

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I'm using GraphQL shopify buy-sdk for Android, and getting node for Product, by string id like:

```
"id" -> "Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0LzEwMDcyMDgwOTc1"
```

this is node id

but to get, say, product metafields, i have to make request to Admin API

```
https://SHOP.myshopify.com/admin/products/{productId}/metafields.json
```

where {productId} is numeric id of Product, like:

```
6243834538
```

I cannot use node id in REST API request, getting 400 "Bad Request".

**So the question is** - how to get numeric product id for node in GraphQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do a base64 decode to the string id. By decoding (base64) the string you gave in the example I found something like this.

gid://shopify/Product/10072080975

You can trim the string to get the product id from the end and can use in the rest api of shopify admin api.

Comment: Shopify docs say that this id is opaque and will not guaranteed follow this structure. https://help.shopify.com/en/api/graphql-admin-api/migrating_from_rest#graphql-ids-are-opaque